# Delphi 5: value of constant changes when it gets passed as function parameter

Tags: delphi, memory, constants

I have one spot in very old code (15 years) that has just started acting up:

cTemp := tblMemList.FieldByName('TTType').AsString;

in Delphi's DB.pas, the FieldByName function's passed "FieldName" constant shows a value of 'lick on Save or Cancel', not 'TTType'.

I thought at first that it might be caused by being in a somewhat large pas unit (about 17k lines), so I broke it up into two pas units, but with no effect.

I'm stumped.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Defect in your code seems likely. Please show a [mcve].

Comment: Obvious question:  What have you changed in the source since it was last working correctly?  Anyway, the symptom sounds like a memory overwrite.  Have you tried using FastMM4?  That can catch things like that.

Comment: (Not sure if this is how to respond to suggestions)    I installed FastMM4 as suggested, and it did find one memory  leak, but fixing that had no effect on the problem.  I still get an AV when that line runs.    As to showing an example, I'm not sure what else to post.  When I F7 this line, it goes immediately to the FieldByName function and the value that is passed as a parameter is NOT the value that shows in my  code.  That's all there is to it.  Before the F7, it is 'TTType'; after I press F7 it appears as 'lick onSave or Cancel'.

Answer (score 0):

The cause ended up being too many components on one form.  It had about 1,500 components on it.  When I removed about 300,  the problem went away.  It felt like a memory/resources issue.

So, my next step is to re-structure that form so that I can get 1,500 (or more) components on it without causing this problem again.

If anyone has any suggestions on other solutions, I would love to hear them.

Answer (score -1):

I would use an intermediary to debug:

```
field := tblMemList.FieldByName ('TTTYpe') ;
cTemp := field.asString ;
```

Comment: This is not an answer and should be a comment

Comment: Yes it can. And in any case that's no excuse. Don't write comments as answers.